# Java library for YAML to JAXB mapping

Tags: java, jaxb, yaml

I am looking for a Java library for YAML parsing that would be a drop-in replacement for existing XML + JAXB solution (migrating config from XML to YAML). For popular libraries I found nothing on JAXB support, however I tend to believe some libraries should offer that (like Jackson, which provides JSON mapping based on JAXB).

Or is JAXB a not-so-good way to go with YAML, and I should rewrite my mapping using JavaBeans or such?

Answer (score 1):

Jackson has com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.yaml.JacksonJaxbYAMLProvider